# What is the difference between should and must in scala testing?

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, specs2

Both scalatest and Specs2 have separate matchers for `should` and `must`.

However, I cannot find any explanation for why you would use one or the other.

What exactly is the difference?

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't find that duplicate via Google nor SO search.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, this is purely a syntactic preference. I personally prefer to use `must` in specs2 because I think that `should` can make people think that an expectation is optional.