# Specs2 comparison of strings doesn't work with should

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm using specs2 and my understanding is that `must` and `should` are equivalent (see [What is the difference between should and must in scala testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435701/what-is-the-difference-between-should-and-must-in-scala-testing)), and using one or the other is just a personal preference.

However, when comparing Strings, the following test using `must` works:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

class StringEqualWithMust extends Specification {

  "string comp " should {
    "abc" must beEqualTo("abc")
  }
}
```

But the same test using `should` won't compile:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

class StringEqualWithShould extends Specification {

  "string comp " should {
    "abc" should beEqualTo("abc")
  }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
StringEqualWithShould.scala:7: overloaded method value should with alternatives:
[error]   (fs: => org.specs2.specification.core.Fragments)(implicit p1: org.specs2.control.ImplicitParameters.ImplicitParam1)org.specs2.specification.core.Fragments <and>
[error]   (f: => org.specs2.specification.core.Fragment)org.specs2.specification.core.Fragment
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.specs2.matcher.BeEqualTo)
[error]     "abc" should beEqualTo("abc")
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
```

Why is there a difference between `must` and `should` when comparing Strings ?

I'm using sbt 0.13.8, scala 2.12.0, and specs2 3.8.6

Comment: The expected structure for mutable spec is `should` (> `>>`) > `in` and `must` with matcher

Comment: Which version of specs2 are you using? Can you try with `3.8.6`?

Comment: Same result with version 3.8.6

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty comes from the fact that `should` can be used to open a block of examples but also to describe an expectation. You can workaround this by mixing in the following trait

```
import org.specs2.specification.core._
import org.specs2.control.ImplicitParameters._
import org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.ExampleDsl

trait NoShouldBlock extends ExampleDsl {

  override def describe(s: String) = super.describe(s)

  implicit class block(d: String) {
    def >>(f: => Fragment): Fragment = describe(d).>>(f)
    def >>(fs: => Fragments)(implicit p1: ImplicitParam1): Fragments =     describe(d).>>(fs)(p1)
  }

}
```

And then write your specification like

```
class StringEqualWithShould extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification with NoShouldBlock {

  "string comp" >> {
    "first example" >> {
      "abc" should beEqualTo("abc")
    }
    "second example" >> {
      "def" should beEqualTo("def")
    }
  }
}
```